# How to disable select feature of list-box

Tags: user-interface, listbox, racket, selection

I like to generate a table in GUI without the feature of **selection**. I tried changing in choices and style, but the selection feature still remains as shown in the screenshot.

[image: The selection in blue highlight]

```
(define list-box
  (new list-box% [label #f]
       [parent top-frame]
       [choices '()]
       [style '(extended column-headers)]
       [columns (list "No." "Fruit" "Color")]      
       [stretchable-width #t]
       [stretchable-height #t])) 
(send list-box set data)
```

If I used [enabled #f], the column-width can't be adjusted anymore and longer text in column is hidden. Is there some way to disable select feature without showing "..." after text, it means showing the full text in the column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a callback function to clear a selection as soon as it is made:

```
(new list-box% 
     [parent top-frame]
     [style '(single)] ; use 'single so at most one row is selected
     ;; ...
     [callback (lambda (list-box . _)
                 (define selection (send list-box get-selection))
                 (when selection (send list-box select selection #f)))]))
```

This does sometimes result in a short flash as one item is selected and quickly deselected.  To avoid it, you can inherit from `list-box%` and intercept mouse events in the subclass:

```
(define unselectable-list-box%
  (class list-box%
    (super-new)
    (define/override (on-subwindow-event window event) #t)))

(define list-box
  (new unselectable-list-box%
       [parent top-frame]
       [style '(multiple ; does NOT work with 'single 
                clickable-headers)]
       ;; ...
       ))
```

A click on the header will still generate a `column-control-event` if `clickable-headers` is set.

In this solution, note the use of `'multiple` in `style`; there's something about `'single` that makes the list-box want to have something selected after a click, even when the mouse events are intercepted.

Comment: There is still blue highlight flashing once when the item in list-box is clicked. User might get confused if it is software error when they try clicking the item. I am trying to hide that blue highlight.

Comment: Thanks, @Toat.  I didn't notice at first.  The second option (in the edit) should avoid that.

Comment: It works, @ohspite. `[style '(single clickable-headers)]` also works in the second option. I always get confused when it's time to define a new class like unselectable-list-box% and still not familiar with the usage like define/override. Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: But, scroll bar still can't be used if the list is longer than the frame-height while it's able to drag clickable-headers, @ohspite.

Comment: In Linux, or at least on my machine, the scroll bars do work (and it still selects things if using `[style '(single)]`).  Maybe when working at this level there is different behavior on different platforms.  You could experiment with examining the events and blocking just those that are clicks. (Returning `#t` from `on-subwindow-event` blocks further mouse-handling and `#f` allows it.  See the [mouse-event% docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/mouse-event_.html?q=list-box) for the list of event types.)

Comment: Yes, the scroll bar works in Ubuntu, I installed Ubuntu in my computer and tested. It also works for both `[style '(single clickable-headers)]` and `[style '(multiple clickable-headers)], @ohspite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set-coumn-width`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/list-box_.html?q=set-column-width#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._list-box~25%29._set-column-width%29%29) to set the width of a particular column, even if the table is not enabled. The method also takes a min and max width, this sets bounds on large or small the width can be, but only matters if the list is enabled.

Additionally, as you noticed, if you disable the list, the user won't be able to select an item as well.

So, to put it all together, you can create a table where you can set the width, as well as prevent the user from clicking it by doing:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define top-frame (new frame%
                       [label "Example"]
                       [width 500]
                       [height 500]))

(define list-box
  (new list-box% [label #f]
       [parent top-frame]
       [choices '()]
       [style '(extended column-headers)]
       [columns (list "No." "Fruit" "Color")]
       [enabled #f]
       [stretchable-width #t]
       [stretchable-height #t])) 
(send list-box set '("1" "2" "3") '("4" "5" "6") '("7" "8" "9"))
(send list-box set-column-width 0 10 10 10)
(send list-box set-column-width 1 100 100 100)
(send list-box set-column-width 2 50 50 50)

(send top-frame show #t)
```

Comment: Using `[enabled #f]` also make the **scroll bar inactive** as it is ignoring every mouse click. If the list is longer than frame-height, the rest of the list can't be accessed by scrolling down.

Comment: I have tested with [number-of-visible-items](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/list-box_.html?q=set-column-width#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._list-box~25%29._number-of-visible-items%29%29), but it didn't change anything in GUI.

Comment: Ah, do you want the user to be able to scroll, or do you just want to make sure that the window is big enough to change the table? Because you could also just increase the height of the window as well.

Comment: I want the user to be able to scroll. The list I actually use for list-box is so long and all the list can't be visible even I increase the frame height as the height of window.